# Show in gridView Specific column of Table using Entity Framework 6.0

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

What I want is this:

```
DataTable dt=mystaticClass.gettableFuction("select col1,col2,col3,col4 from table1 where date between (date1 and date2) and  id=(select max(id) from table1)");
```

Now I want my data-table to be filled using linq expression.I tried this.

```
 lamiEntities1 lam = new lamiEntities1();
    var pay = from p in lam.Mytablename.AsEnumerable()
              where p.Date > start && p.Date < end
              select new
              {
                  Column1 = p.col1,
                  Column2 = p.col2
                  Column3 = p.col2
                  Column4 = p.col2
              };
```

Here is don't know how to call max function to get record of `max(Id)`

```
grid1.datasource = pay;
```

Here I'm getting only one column1 value, not entire row with 4 columns

If I remove

```
   select new
          {
              Column1 = p.col1,
              Column2 = p.col2
              Column3 = p.col2
              Column4 = p.col2
          };
```

and change it to

```
 select p;
```

I get all unwanted columns including my 4 columns.

I'm using Mysql and Entity Framework 6.1.3.

Comment: You need to drop the `select p;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do using `let` expression by storing the maximum Id of table in it like this:-

```
var pay = from p in lam.Mytablename.AsEnumerable()
          let maxid = lam.Mytablename.AsEnumerable().Max(x => x.Field<int>("Id"))
          where p.Date > start && p.Date < end && p.Field<int>("id") == maxid 
          select new
                {
                    Column1 = p.col1,
                    Column2 = p.col2,
                    Column3 = p.col2,
                    Column4 = p.col2
                };
```

As a side note I don't think you will get properties like this `p.col1` from a DataTable directly (I guess you have shown that just for example), good way to retrieve the values is with `Field` as I did while comparing the id's.

Answer (score 2):

I think, you need to `,`. Just use `,` between columns in select new:If you try like this first solution will work.

```
 lamiEntities1 lam = new lamiEntities1();
    var pay = from p in lam.Mytablename.AsEnumerable()
              where p.Date > start && p.Date < end
              select new
              {
                  Column1 = p.col1,
                  Column2 = p.col2,
                  Column3 = p.col2,
                  Column4 = p.col2,
              };
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you are searching for the LINQ equivalent of the following SQL query

```
select col1,col2,col3 from table1 where date between (date1 and date2) and id=(select max(id) from table1)
```

First, let make the SQL query a bit more readable

```
select t.col1, t.col2, t.col3
from table1 as t
where t.date between (startDate and endDate)
    and id=(select max(t1.id) from table1 as t1)
```

an then translate it to LINQ

```
var query = 
from t in db.table1
where t.date >= startDate && t.date <= endDate
    && t.id == db.table1.Max(t1 => t1.id)
select new { t.col1, t.col2, t.col3, t.col4 };
```

As you can see, in this case it's almost one to one mapping.

Answer (score 1):

```
var abc = (from q in lam.Mytablename.AsEnumerable()
           where q.Id == (from p in lam.Mytablename.AsEnumerable() select p).Max(x => x.Id) 
                 && q.Date > start && q.Date < end
           select new
                       {
                            Column1 = p.col1,
                            Column2 = p.col2,
                            Column3 = p.col2,
                            Column4 = p.col2   
                       });
```